# I graduated but school is withholding my degree

Tags: degree, graduation, community-college

I graduated in 2016 for my Associates Degree. My college told me to enroll in history 11 over at a different college (they dropped me from the class by mistake and I couldn’t get back into it because it was full), that it’s equivalent to their 111 American History, so I did. I gave my college the transcripts, transcripts accepted it. Upon finishing my checklist counseling and admissions signed off my “petition to graduate” form. I walked the stage, paid for cap and gown, paid for my graduation pictures, and then as they gave everyone else their actual diploma months later, they informed me that they aren’t going to give me my degree because the other college does not match their American institution portion. I spoke to head of admissions and she was going to give it to me since I wasn’t going to use it to transfer, I’d just needed it for employers! (Degree in communications). Now, since she is now the Dean, she’s refusing to give it to me, even though THEY signed off. It has to go through several steps for the petition and still she is now blaming me for not taking their course too. I already took it at another college, what do I do now?

Comment: I feel for you, as my sister had something like this happen where she was denied her degree and the entire direction of her life got derailed.  But this sounds extremely specific to your particular situation and university, so I'm not sure there's much we can do, other than to tell you to go through whatever your university's process is and maybe consult a lawyer if you can.

Comment: If they signed you off, then you may be able to approach the Governing Board, or as well, the Accrediting Institution for the college but you should find some good independent advice - a lawyer specialising in that area possibly..